Attribute error in densenet121 after 2nd epoch
im trying to train DenseNet 121 model but i keep on getting this error. First epoch finishes, then second starts and error occurs. Please help.
Hyperparameters:
{'epochs': 30, 'lr': 0.001, 'lr_decay': 0.9, 'lam_recon': 0.392, 'debug': True, 'save_dir': 'saveDir', 'weights': None}
Epoch 1/30
D:\Instalki\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\trainers\data_adapters\py_dataset_adapter.py:121: UserWarning: Your PyDataset class should call super().__init__(**kwargs) in its constructor. **kwargs can include workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size. Do not pass these arguments to fit(), as they will be ignored.
self._warn_if_super_not_called()
81/81 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 26s/step - accuracy: 0.6777 - loss: 0.8694
Epoch 1: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.77680, saving model to saveDir/weights.weights.h5
81/81 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2426s 29s/step - accuracy: 0.6791 - loss: 0.8657 - val_accuracy: 0.7768 - val_loss: 0.5253 - learning_rate: 0.0010
Epoch 2/30
D:\Instalki\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py:158: UserWarning: Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least steps_per_epoch * epochs batches. You may need to use the .repeat() function when building your dataset.
self.gen.throw(value)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 27
     24 if args.save_dir is not None and not os.path.exists(args.save_dir):
     25     os.makedirs(args.save_dir)
---> 27 history = train(model=model,
     28                 train_generator=train_generator,
     29                 validation_generator=validation_generator,
     30                 args=args)

Cell In[14], line 16, in train(model, train_generator, validation_generator, args)
     12 tb = TensorBoard(log_dir=args.save_dir + '/logs', histogram_freq=1)
     14 early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
---> 16 model.fit(train_generator,
     17           steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator),
     18           epochs=args.epochs,
     19           validation_data=validation_generator,
     20           validation_steps=len(validation_generator),
     21           callbacks=[log, tb, checkpoint, lr_decay, early_stopping])
     23 model.save_weights(args.save_dir + '/trained_model_weights.h5')
     24 print('Trained model weights saved to \'%s/trained_model_weights.h5\'' % args.save_dir)

File D:\Instalki\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File D:\Instalki\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py:350, in TensorFlowTrainer.fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq)
    329         self._eval_epoch_iterator = TFEpochIterator(
    330             x=val_x,
    331             y=val_y,
   (...)
    337             shuffle=False,
    338         )
    339     val_logs = self.evaluate(
    340         x=val_x,
    341         y=val_y,
   (...)
    347         _use_cached_eval_dataset=True,
    348     )
    349     val_logs = {
--> 350         "val_" + name: val for name, val in val_logs.items()
    351     }
    352     epoch_logs.update(val_logs)
    354 callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'

Here is my code:
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import DenseNet121
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import CSVLogger, ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler, TensorBoard

batch_size = 64
image_shape=(524,524)

train_dir = "brain-tumor-mri-dataset/Training"
test_dir = "brain-tumor-mri-dataset/Testing"
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=10,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest',
    validation_split=0.1
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=image_shape,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training'
)

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=image_shape,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation'
)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=image_shape,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='categorical'
)
def create_densenet_model(input_shape=(524,524,3), num_classes=4):
    densenet121_base = DenseNet121(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)

    for layer in densenet121_base.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    x = densenet121_base.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
    predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=densenet121_base.input, outputs=predictions)
    return model

model = create_densenet_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

def train(model,
          train_generator,
          validation_generator,
          args):

    log = CSVLogger(args.save_dir + '/log.csv')
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(args.save_dir + '/weights.weights.h5', monitor='val_accuracy',
                             save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, verbose=1)
    
    lr_decay = LearningRateScheduler(schedule=lambda epoch: args.lr * (args.lr_decay ** epoch))

    tb = TensorBoard(log_dir=args.save_dir + '/logs', histogram_freq=1)

    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)

    model.fit(train_generator,
              steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator),
              epochs=args.epochs,
              validation_data=validation_generator,
              validation_steps=len(validation_generator),
              callbacks=[log, tb, checkpoint, lr_decay, early_stopping])

    model.save_weights(args.save_dir + '/trained_model_weights.h5')
    print('Trained model weights saved to \'%s/trained_model_weights.h5\'' % args.save_dir)

    return model

class Args:
    def __init__(self, epochs=50, lr=0.001, lr_decay=0.9, lam_recon=0.392, routings=3, shift_fraction=0.1, debug=False, save_dir='./result', testing=False, digit=5, weights=None):
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.lr = lr
        self.lr_decay = lr_decay
        self.lam_recon = lam_recon
        self.debug = debug
        self.save_dir = save_dir
        self.weights = weights

args = Args(
    epochs=30,
    lr=0.001,
    lr_decay=0.9,
    lam_recon=0.392,
    debug=True,
    save_dir='saveDir',
    weights=None
)

print("Hyperparameters:")
print(args.__dict__)

if args.save_dir is not None and not os.path.exists(args.save_dir):
    os.makedirs(args.save_dir)

history = train(model=model,
                train_generator=train_generator,
                validation_generator=validation_generator,
                args=args)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi @Natalia Marszał,The error you're encountering appears to be related to how Keras is handling the validation data during the training process. Specifically, the AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items' error typically means that there was an issue with the validation data, which resulted in a None value being passed where a dictionary was expected.

Make sure that the validation_generator is correctly configured and supplying data. It’s important that the validation generator effectively yields batches of data and labels during training. Verify that train_datagen.flow_from_directory() is properly set up for the validation subset.The model.fit() method expects steps_per_epoch and validation_steps to be integers. Ensure these are integers and correctly represent the number of batches per epoch and validation step.
